# remove() not working when trying to remove <li> generated from a button

Tags: jquery

I have a button that adds li to the ordered list. Within this item added, there is a delete button. I'm trying to have this button nested within the li delete itself and parent but remove() does not seem to work.

```js
$('.add').click(()=>{
  var item = "<li>Item - <button class='delete'>Delete</button></li>"
  
  $('ol').append(item);
  
});

$('ol').on( 'click','.delete' ,(e)=>{
  console.log('clicked');
  
  $(e).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>

</ol>
<button class='add'>Add</button>
```

Comment: Reference Carsten's answer.  `e` is the event.  `e.target` is the actual button clicked.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(e.target).parent().remove();`, since `e.target` tells what element was clicked.

The reason your `add` function works, it because you don't have to interact with the element you click on.

**Demo**

```js
$('.add').click(()=>{
  var item = "<li>Item - <button class='delete'>Delete</button></li>"
  
  $('ol').append(item);
  
});

$('ol').on( 'click','.delete' ,(e)=>{
  
  $(e.target).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>

</ol>
<button class='add'>Add</button>
```

Comment: What is $(e) and $(e).parent() then? Just curious. I don't know anything about jQuery

Comment: `e` is the event, which doesn't have a parent.  so `parent()` would returned undefined or something of the like

Comment: @Taplar: and $(e) is equivalent to e?

Comment: No, `$(e)` would be a jQuery object, containing the event object.

Comment: And that one does not have a parent either?

Comment: No, events are not attached to the DOM.  They do not exist in the DOM structure.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
$('ol').on('click', '.delete', function () {
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: What happens if he tries it? Will it work? Why? What's the difference?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I just had to double check the code... Geeeezzz tough around here... lol

Comment: "It works" is a poor answer.  "This fixes your problem, and here is why it fixes it" is a great answer.

Comment: Yes, SO is a tough place. It was for me, too. But it makes askers better askers and answerers better educators.

Comment: I agree, I'm updating my answer to explain in more detail.